# Unknown type name class

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I have the following header files:

https://gist.github.com/wemakeweb/5501443
and the compiler always reports **"Unknown Type name Class"**. I have included Forward Declaration, to break circular including , where i think i have to. What did i forget?

**Edit**: i put it all in one header file, and the compiler still reports "expected ; after top level declarator"

https://gist.github.com/wemakeweb/5583500

**Edit 2**
Now im getting linker errors. "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"

**Solved, Problems were**

1. Circular Including
2. main.c instead of main.cpp
3. the actual code was in a static lib which was not linked properly

Comment: On what line of the example? What compiler are you using, and with what compile options?

Comment: Now you haven't shown the ilnker errors you're getting. You've got to try harder if you want people to help you solve things.

Comment: yeah you are right, i posted the link errors only as comment to roddys answer

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This error? `error: unknown type name ‘class’`

You're probably compiling it as C rather than C++.

Make sure your source file has a `.cpp` extension, and than any relevant compiler flags are set correctly. (It helps if you include the *exact* error message and line numbers.  Don't try and retype, just cut+paste.)

Comment: the first error i get in the Header file is  "expected ; after top level declarator"

Comment: @SepOSep Yes, but what line number and file? There's nothing wrong with the header file, so also show the cpp source that's trying to include it. You do *have* a .cpp file, don't you?

Comment: Yes it was an main.c file and i now changed it to main.cpp . Im now fighting against a Linker error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64".

Comment: @SepOSep : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110184/c-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-when-compiling-on-mac-osx-lion

Answer (score 7):

You have at least one cyclic include dependency between `Feld.h` and `Figur.h`. The forward declarations have no effect if you also include the headers. Just remove the includes.