# Error in creating a class header file

Tags: c++, class, header

I am attempting to create a simple class header file. I have done the following so far:

```
#ifndef RECORD_H
#define RECORD_H

class Records{
    int idNumber;
    int serialNumber;

public:
    Records();
};

#endif
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> [Error] unknown type name 'class'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you including and compiling it? I get that error if I use a C compiler instead of a C++ compiler.

Comment: This is a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336244/unknown-type-name-class

Comment: Ok thank you all for your help. I did not realize that it depended on the main source file using the header. It now works.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably compiling it as C rather than C++. That is why you are getting that error..

Make sure your source file has a .cpp extension.

Answer (score 0):

As lakesh said, you may to compiling as C rather than C++.  Most compiler use the file extension to determine how to compile the file (use `.cpp` instead of `.c`)

If that's not it, then the problem would probably be in the a different file loaaded before this.

```
    // Record.cpp
    #include "badfile.h"   // error in here
    #include "record.h"    // error showing up here.
```