# client server program in C

Tags: c

I have written a simple client server program in which server accepts messages from clients and prints their details (hard coded for my assignment). I had written this at first on a Linux (Fedora) machine, and it was working perfectly fine. But when I try to compile the server code on my mac, it doesn't work.

Here is the message after compilation:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_error", referenced from:
      _main in cc3O1167.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Really hard to help you with this one, you are probably using a different standard C library which is causing the issue of the Symbol not existing.. I'd suggest running ld with the -lc flag.

Comment: You have compatibility issues. Is your Fedora 32bit?

Comment: Strip your program down to the minimum to replicate the problem, then post that code here.  I have a Mac, but can't help you without any code.

Comment: What's the command you're typing to compile?

Answer (score 3):

Put this at the top of your main file:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#  define error printf
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

From "man 3 error":

```
   These functions and variables are GNU extensions,  and  should  not  be
   used in programs intended to be portable.
```

So, do not use this function in programs that need to work on non-GNU systems, or provide your own replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Your `error` function is probably in another file than the main file, you are including its declaration but not its implementation:

Try to compile like this:

```
g++ main.c -l<filetolink>
```

filetolink being the name of the file containing the implementation of the `error` function (without the extension)

Reference: [C - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when compiling on Mac OSX Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110184/c-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-when-compiling-on-mac-osx-lion)
Seems to have multiple solutions to this problem when googling the first error line